# How do I change outside access number from 8 to 9 in Cisco UCM?

Tags: cisco, voip, telephony

I want to change my outside access number from 8 to 9 in Cisco Unified Communications Manager. I've copied all of my 9.x route patterns to create a duplicate set of 8.x route patterns.

When I try to dial an outside number using (i.e. 8.1-800-444-4444), I hear the "Your call cannot be completed as dialed" recording.

All of the new 8.x route patterns are in the same partitions as the 9.x patterns. Do I need to delete the 9.x patterns before the 8.x patterns will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to updating all of the route patterns in CUCM, I had to modify dial peers on my router. Example dial-peer configuration with an 8 prefix:

```
dial-peer voice 900 pots
 description 10 digit local dialing
 destination-pattern 8410[2-9]......$
 port 0/0/0:23
 forward-digits 10
```